# Laravel Eager Loading with some where conditions in both ends

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting the sql query as this:

> select * from `geofilter_activations` where not exists (select * from `snap_submissions` where `geofilter_activations`.`purchase_id` = `snap_submissions`.`purchase_id`) and `status` = 0 and `created_at` < 2018-10-10 07:15:42 order by `id` desc limit 1

But what happened to the query i added wherenotnull of subscription_id? 
It's not coming in the query output. Give me a way to optimise the query and make it work.

```
    $time_before = '10';
    $dt = Carbon::now();

    $activation = GeofilterActivation::doesntHave('submission_data')
        ->where('status', '0')
        ->where('created_at', '<', $dt->subMinutes($time_before)->toDateTimeString())
        ->OrderBy('id','desc')
        ->first();

    $activation->load(['purchase' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('subscription_id');
    }]);
```

And the GeoFilterActivation Model is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Geofilter;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GeofilterActivation extends Model
{
    public function purchase(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Geofilter\GeofilterPurchase', 'purchase_id');
    }
    public function submission_data(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Geofilter\SnapSubmission', 'purchase_id', 'purchase_id');
    }

    public function ad_stat(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Geofilter\SnapAdStat', 'purchase_id', 'purchase_id');
    }

    public function currency(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Currency', 'currency_code', 'code');
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you "getting the sql query"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines can help you:

```
$result = GeofilterActivation::with(['purchase' => function($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('subscription_id');
    }])
    ->doesntHave('submission_data')
    ->where('status','0')
    ->where('created_at', '<', $dt->subMinutes($time_before)->toDateTimeString())
    ->OrderBy('id','desc')
    ->first();
```

The reason why your query didn't include that `load` is because `load` is called after your query executes, so you have to include the relationship in the query with using `with`. The example you mentioned above with load is actually `lazy load` because you are requesting an object when it's needed.

Comment: When i give like this i get the query as this : ** select * from `geofilter_activations` where not exists (select * from `snap_submissions` where `geofilter_activations`.`purchase_id` = `snap_submissions`.`purchase_id`) and `status` = 0 and `created_at` < 2018-10-10 07:52:43 order by `id` desc limit 1) **

Comment: What if u change the order of chained methods, try calling `with` first then `doesntHave`, I've updated the answer

Comment: Still error @Nikola Gavric
$result = GeofilterActivation::with(['purchase' => function($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('subscription_id');
        }])->doesntHave('submission_data')->where('status','0')
            ->where('created_at1', '<', $dt->subMinutes($time_before)->toDateTimeString())->OrderBy('id','desc')->first();


`select * from `geofilter_activations` where not exists (select * from `snap_submissions` where `geofilter_activations`.`purchase_id` = `snap_submissions`.`purchase_id`) and `status` = 0 and `created_at` < 2018-10-10 08:50:13 order by `id` desc limit 1)`

Comment: What do you need `submission_data` for? Can you remove it from the query or it is crucial?

Comment: Yes it's crucial , it has be there as condition to get data only if the submission_data table is empty

Comment: Submission_data is a table? Can you include the migration file for it then?